# Force Entity Framework to ignore all foreign keys during class generation

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am using the Entity Framework just to create classes that can be mapped to database tables. We have our own data access layer that I need to go through, which is why I'm only using the generated classes.

I would like the entity framework to generate foreign keys as properties instead of classes. So, basically, when it generates classes, I need it to ignore all the foreign keys.

Alternatively, I'm OK with deleting the FK links manually, but I can't figure out how to then regenerate the classes other than syncing from the DB.

I know that .Net 4.0 beta should support this out of the box with the new FK associations, but we're not ready to move up to this, yet. I was thinking that I may be able to use .Net 4.0 to generate the classes and plug them into my 3.5 project, but I doubt this would be smooth sailing.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks so much for any input.

Comment: Wow, my first question and I got got the tumbleweed badge :-)

Maybe I should rephrase my question. Anybody have any recommendation on the best way to generate simple C# classes that each map to a db table? 

Maybe nhibernate or subsonic are the way to go? I don't think the entity framework will need my needs based on it's (IMHO) not so great attempt to handle foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just sucked it up and created partial classes to expose foreign keys as properties. If anybody knows a better way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can check a box in the EF wizard "Include foreign key columns in the model” which generates both a navigation link and properties for foreign keys.